# How to use `request` in custom `list_display` fields to get the logged-in user's `id` in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, userid, django-request

I want to create a hyperlink (custom field in display_list) and I have to use logged-in user's `id` as a part of query parameters in the link.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: `list_display` on the admin page?

Comment: link which has user id corresponding to model instance, when clicked navigates to user details, something like this i presume?

Comment: ^Yeah, I'm assuming the same. This would be straightforward though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the model admin's get_list_display method to access the `request` object and you can add your custom method inside that method where it can access the request object.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

Class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   def get_list_display(self, request):
        def custom_url_method(obj):
            user = request.user
            return format_html("<a href='http://url.com/{0}'>link</a>", user.pk)

        return ['model_field_1', 'model_field_2', custom_url_method]
```

Comment: It's exactly I want! tnx.

Answer (score 0):

for this implement you can create function and return the html file to your admin panel and pass the content to your html than render in admin panel with `render_to_string`

for example:

in your `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from .models import CustomModel

class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('model_field 1', 'custom_link', 'model_field 2',)

    def custom_link(self, object):
        return render_to_string('custom.html', {'content':'content'})
    custom_link.allow_tags = True

admin.site.register(CustomModel, CustomAdmin)
```

in `template/custom.html`:

```
<a href="{% url 'app:view' request.user.id %}">custom link {{content}}</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/app/view/{{request.user.id}}/">custom link {{content}}</a>
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: There is a simpler approach that Aniket Pawar mentioned it. Tnx by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my Understanding, you need to have a **link** which takes `user.id` to send you somewhere according to your requirement. In my code i navigate to `user` detail page of that particular user inside `admin`.

`Admin.py`

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['field1', 'field2', 'anotherfield', 'link_to_user']


def link_to_user(self, obj):

    link = reverse("admin:auth_user_change", args=[obj.model_name.user.id])

    return format_html('<a href="{}"> {}</a>', link, obj.model_name.user.id)

link_to_user.short_description = 'UserID'
```

Comment: Tnx, but  I need to current logged-in user in admin panel! Your approach is good for user of model!

Answer (score 0):

You can return a hyperlink with the current user's `id` in the custom fields of [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) by overriding [get_list_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display) as shown below. *You can see [the original code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1088C1-L1093C33) of `get_list_display()` in GitHub:

```py
from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('test',)

    def (self, request):
        self.request = request # Set `request`
        return self.list_display

    def test(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            "<a href='http://url.com/{0}'>link</a>", 
            request.user.id
        (
```